# Select all records of data table with pagination

Tags: jsf

Hello I want to select all rows of data table but select all header only select the current page records . I am using prime faces data table with pagination.  Is there any to do this ?

Comment: I downvoted this question to due to a lack of investigation. But since the concept of a 'selectReallyAll' is not that weird, I posted a conceptual answer anyway

Comment: Which table, plain jsf, primefaces? Which primefaces? 5.1,5.2,5.3? Posting **mcve** will be highly appreciated http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is by design not possible from the datatable. But you can create something outside the datatable that e.g. when a selectAll IN the datatable is done, an additional link or button is shown where you can click on to do a 'selectReallyAll' in a backingbean. GMail has (had) a similar concept.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but can you please provide some code snippet for example?

Comment: You've already found the select all functionality. The PrimeFaces documentation has the info about the related event (toggleSelect) and how to show a panel/overlay as a result of an ajax call is widely available on the internet as is having a link in there that calls a cremote bean